# При получении ответа с биржи FTX в формате выводится только первый символ

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, строки, словари

Пытаюсь получить доступ к элементу массива при получении ответа с биржи.
Ответ приходит в таком виде:

```
{
    "channel": "orderbook", 
    "market": "BTC-PERP", 
    "type": "update", 
    "data": {
        "time": 1618744331.0699444, 
        "checksum": 3938867283, 
        "bids": [[54888.0, 4.1005], [54887.0, 1.2235], [54852.0, 0.1459], [54793.0, 0.0464], [54742.0, 0.0]], 
        "asks": [], 
        "action": "update"
    }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь вывести только один элемент, например, `print(msg["data"])`, то выводится ошибка:

> `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Если делаю вариант `jsr = json.loads(msg)`, а потом обращаюсь к элементу `print(jsr["data"])`, все равно выводится та же ошибка.
Если делаю вариант `msg[0]` или `jsr[0]`, выводится лишь первый символ строки, то есть `"{"`

Как можно вывести элемент, например, `"data"`?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

указывает на тип переменной string. С помощью json.loads() нормально переводится в словарь:

```
my_str = '{"channel": "orderbook", "market": "BTC-PERP", "type": "update", "data": {"time": 1618744331.0699444, "checksum": 3938867283, "bids": [[54888.0, 4.1005], [54887.0, 1.2235], [54852.0, 0.1459], [54793.0, 0.0464], [54742.0, 0.0]], "asks": [], "action": "update"}}'

import json
my_dict = json.loads(my_str)
```

пробуем:

```
>>> type(my_dict)
<class 'dict'>
```

обращаемся как к словарю:

```
>>> my_dict['data']['bids'][0]
[54888.0, 4.1005]
```